# A Case For Writing Integration Test Without Assertions

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I am developing simple telephone call system.
One of my requirement is getting DTMF values (simply telephone digits pressed by callee) from callee.

While writing **Integration Test**, I found myself in a situation where my Integration test has no Assert :because the actual callee may not enter any dtmf value and I can not know what he-she will enter in advance.  I can not write any assertion in my integration test.

And It seems that my Integration Tests become manual test without assertions: I make a call, answer it with dtmf values and check log if the entered DTMF values are correct manually.

For practical purposes, I write integration tests without assert for now.

But wonder, if there is a better way to test this? Actually, how  the telephony companies write their test in such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing what the phone system does in a "real life" situation

In this "real life" situation there are two conditions

1) DTMF values are used

2) DTMF values are not used

The way to test is to either

a) have a scripted "callee" who will predictably press (or not press) the phone buttons.  This will control the inputs

or

b) test the data independently so you know if you are in condition 1) or 2)

Once you have done one of the above you will know if you are in condition 1) or 2)

In condition 1) you might check that the correct values are logged, or that something is logged and assert a condition based on that

In condition 2) you can check for the absence of logged data and assert a condition that the data is not present

Comment: It is hard for me to have a scripted "callee" who will predictably press (or not press) the phone buttons. But can assume that the callee will enter x value or nothing.

Comment: No one said testing was easy

Comment: Testing should be easy.I wanted to configure my enviroment easily to run integration tests so that I can quickly get feedback.